# Embedded questions with 'be'

Tags: word-order, subjects

I know that we should use the normal word order in embedded questions, for ex. 'I don' t know what she did', and with 'be'-'I don' t know where she is', and with subject questions 'I don' t know who said it'.

1. But what happens with subject questions using 'be'? For ex, if we want to use as an imbedded question this one: 'who is he?', 'what is this/it?', 'which one is he?'. Do we say 'I don' t know what this is/it is/which one he is'?. It sounds weird.
2. In the subject questions the question word is the subject, but is this the case in questions with 'be'? Are they subject questions or not? How to identify the subject in 'who is she?' ( she is my friend'/'my friend is she', regardless how strange this sounds).
3. Is there any difference in terms of finding the subject between 'who is he' and 'which one is he'. I've read something about using these structures in the future form, e. g. 'which one will it be' / 'which one will be it' to determine the subject. But does it work with 'who'?

Answer (score 3):

We say "I don’t know what this is" / "which one he is". Note that there is no subject-auxiliary inversion like there is in main clauses, cf "What is this?" / "Which one is he?" In both main and subordinate clauses, "what" and "one" are complements of "be".

Verb agreement often enables us to identify the subject in "be" clauses.

For example, in "Who is she", the subject is "she". We know this because we could replace "she" with "they", which would require that we replace "is" with "are", with the agreement showing that "she" is the subject.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, it is correct to say 'I know who this is'.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. The subject is "this".

Comment: Thank you very much. So we can say 'I know who this is'. But what if we want to make 'who' or 'which' the subject? Can we say 'I know who is this', as in the example 'which one will be you?' Is this also correct? How to understand which word is the subject or the coplement in the original question, apart from given context? I just met 'what' as a subject in an embedded question in some youtube video about another grammar point.

Comment: Are there any cases when we can use the original main clause as a subject question and not invert it in an embedded one, like with normal subject question 'who did this? - I know who did this'?

Comment: In "I know who killed my cat", the subject is "who". No, you can't say *"I know who is this" because embedded questions don't have subject-auxiliary inversion like that. And nor do main clauses if the question word is subject ("Who did this?"). But in main clauses, if the question word is **not** the subject, it triggers subject-auxiliary inversion ("What are they?"), while the embedded question has, as usual, no inversion ("I know what they are").

Comment: Yes, that's great. I see now, but thereare still some questions about this https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145519/which-one-is-you-vs-which-one-are-you. 'which one will be you'. The subject here is 'which one', isn't it? And the embedded question, I suppose, will be 'I don' t know which one will be you/are you? ' I' m sorry, but it's really confusing

Comment: Yes: in "Which one will be you?", the subject is "which one", so there is no inversion. And in the embedded question, as usual there is no inversion either, so we have "I don't know which one will be you". Note that in embedded questions there is normally no subject-auxiliary inversion, but in main clauses if the interrogative phrase is **not** the subject, as in "Which car did you buy", where "which car" is object of "buy", it triggers inversion.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I can see these inversions or non-inversions. A) So, why then is it possible to say 1)'I know whichh one will be you 2)which one will be you?, making which one the subject, 3) I know which one you will be, 4) which one will you be?, making' you' the subject,,, but it's impossible to say 'I know who are you', 'who are you' making 'who the subject? B) And can phrases in 1, 2, be used with' are, not 'will be' : 'I know which one are you'? I suppose they can, because the tense shouldn't change the word order.?

Comment: I understand that in embedded questions we don't  change the correct w.order of subject questions, but only questions where q.w.is not the subject, where we use the normal w.order in embedded ?s instead of inverted forms of main clauses. So, I want to know when it is that we can make 'who' the subject, or in which cases we can consider it as a subject like 'which' to use the main clause as a subject question, and, accordingly, say 'I know who is this'.

Comment: Try to remember the basic rules: Embedded questions do not have inversion. Main clause questions only have inversion if the interrogative phrase is not the subject.

Comment: I know that already thanks to you). Ok, now my question is about pronouns 'who' and 'which one'. Why is it possible for 'which one' to be the subject, but for 'who' it iss not normal.  So, I want to know when it is that we can make 'who' the subject, or in which cases we can consider it as a subject like 'which' to use the main clause as a subject question, and, accordingly, say 'I know who is this'.

Comment: "Who" is the subject in "Who called the police?" We know that "who" is the subject because the answer would be, say, "Ed called the police", where "Ed" is clearly the subject.  The embedded version would be "I know who called the police", where as usual there is no inversion. Note that we can't say *"I know who is this", because the embedded question has inversion. It should be "I know who this is".

Comment: We're returning to the same point again and again, presumably because of me. Could you help me to understand the next: look, you said :'Yes: in "Which one will be you?", the subject is "which one", so there is no inversion. And in the embedded question, as usual there is no inversion either, so we have "I don't know which one will be you".

Comment: So, here it is also possible to say' which one will you be? ' and' I know which one you will be'. In this case the subject is you, not which one, and we can change the subject depending on what we ask, and invert or not invert the structure, right? Why isn't it possible with 'who'?

Comment: Note that I'm asking not only about subject questions, but subject questions with 'be'. In your answer which I mentioned here we can see that subject questions with 'be' exist. So, does it depend on the pronoun? Does the choice between 'which one' and 'who' make it possible or impossible?

Comment: I know 'which one will you be' sounds weird, but isn't it the original question for 'we know which one you will be' because the original question for 'we know which one will be you' should be different, like'which one will be you'. And why is it weirder when we use the present tense of be:'which one you are?(here) - we know which one you are' /'which one are yoi? - we know which one are you(here) '

Comment: I've already answered all those questions. I'm sorry but I can't help you any more.

Comment: Well, I'm not so advanced as to see all the meanings in your answers, sorry for that. Thank you very much so far, I'll be exploring further

Comment: @BillJ I also have the same question as user98919 had; I am not convinced as well. Let us review it again with another example. In the sentence "Physics is the science of nature" I can ask for the **subject** in this way: "What is the science of nature". So, according to the rule you mentioned in the answer and comments, we should **not** have any inversion in an embedded question of the sentence, like "I do not know what is the science of nature", which seems incorrect. Why does the rule not work here?