# Why is inversion applied in some subordinate interrogative clauses when a subject is asked for?

Tags: grammar, word-order, subordinate-clauses, interrogatives, subject-auxiliary-inversion

## Preamble

The main concern of this post was discussed in [this thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/221762/91725). However, both the OP and I were not convinced of the explanation in the existing answer and comments. I tried to talk to the author of the answer in some ways, but I could not. So, regarding [this meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20044/502725) and avoiding having a lengthy discussion in comments, I decided to post this question, involving another way of describing the issue.

## What is the Issue?

As we know, when we want to use a subordinate interrogative clause, we may need to apply inversion, depending on whether the original interrogative clause asks for the subject or not.

For example, we can say:

- *I do not know **who pays the bill***

which does not need inversion; we can also say:

- *I know **who he wants***

which needs inversion.

Now, consider the following sentence and its interrogative form:

- *Physics is the study of nature.*
- *What is the study of nature?*

We see that the interrogative sentence asks for the subject, namely "physics". So, according to the rule, we must be able to say:

- **I know **what is the study of nature***

which is incorrect because the correct form is:

- *I know **what the study of nature is***

Please note that one can argue that the above sentence comes from applying the rule to the original sentence "The study of nature is physics," considering "physics" as a subject complement and considering that its interrogative form asks for the subject complement, so we need inversion. This argument is correct; however, I wonder why we **cannot** apply the rule to the original sentence "Physics is the study of nature," considering "physics" as a subject and considering that its interrogative form asks for the subject.

Comment: You might usefully compare *He doesn't know **what is wrong*** (he doesn't know exactly what's causing some problem) and *He doesn't know **what wrong is*** (a relatively uncommon utterance that would probably be understood to mean he's an amoral sociopath with no concept of right and wrong).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was wondering of this sentence is really incorrect: "I know what is the science of nature". And i think this and the following have same meaning: "I  know what the science of nature is".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for your comment. So, according to your comment, both structures "[main clause]+ *what* + [be] + [subject complement]" and "[main clause]+ *what* + [subject complement] +[be]" are grammatical but having different meanings. Am I right?

Comment: @Man_From_India Thanks for your comment. I agree with your opinion. However, let us wait for FumbleFingers' response.

Comment: Native speakers wouldn't often say *I know what is the science of nature*. Partly because we'd more likely call it *the **study** of nature*, but mainly because ***it's not a question*** - so we *wouldn't* normally apply "subject/verb inversion". Many non-native speakers overuse that inversion (just as they overuse Perfect verb forms), but strictly speaking it's ungrammatical. Generally speaking, *what + [be] + [subject]* is a ***question***, which can't meaningfully be attached to some preceding "main clause". My ***wrong*** example was effectively just a bit of ***use / mention*** wordplay.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. You said, "what + [be] + [subject] is a **question**, which can't meaningfully be attached to some preceding 'main clause'". However, "who pays the bill" is also a question, and it can be attached to the main clause "I do not know", because the subordinate interrogative clause asks for the subject. Can you tell me why such a rule cannot be applied when we deal with the subordinate interrogative clause *what + [be] + [subject complement]*, like "what is the study of nature" which also asks for the subject, namely "physics"?

Comment: I don't know if it helps to consider *I [don't] know who she loves*. That can be transformed into *I know who she **does** love* (no longer "natural" except in some *emphatic* context where *this* "who" is being contrasted with someone else that she *doesn't* love, with very heavy stress on the word ***does***). But it can't and never could be validly transformed into *I know who does she love* - and *that's* the usage non-native speakers often have trouble avoiding.